# Edit box control has limitations accepting pasted text.

Tags: visual-studio-2015, controls, edit

My laptop is a  64-bit HP Zbook17 running Windows 2017 Professional.   I develop Win32 apps using VS 2015 Express C++.  I have noticed that an edit box opened by the following code

```
      hEdit[k] = CreateWindow(
          WC_EDIT
        , L""
        , WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | 
                                                        ES_WANTRETURN    
         , posEdit[4*k+0], posEdit[4*k+1], posEdit[4*k+2], posEdit[4*k+3]
        , hDlg
        , (HMENU)NULL  
        , hInst
        , NULL
        );
```

has some limitations in handling input pasted either from a text editor app or from Word.  These are:

(1) If the text contains a '\n' character or is too long (i.e. > 800 bytes), the edit window will briefly flash the pasted text and then revert to empty.
(2) If otherwise pastable text contains an apostrophe (0x92) character, the edit window will display all text up to that point.

How do I rectify or circumvent these limitations?

ASIDE:

I have a subroutine that launders a text string to rid itself of these problem features (e.g., replace instances of 0x92 with 0x27) but have found no way to incorporate it into my apps.   WM_CHAR message is never issued, and VS 2015 Express apparently cannot compile any on-line suggested method for retrieving text from clipboard.

If I launder the text externally and only paste in one paragraph at a time, everything works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is a definitive answer to my own question, but I've noticed that the addition of WS_VSCROLL has resolved all of the limitations I had experienced.
Keeping fingers crossed for the time being.